# MSVC accepts std::string array initialized with string literal but gcc and clang rejects

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, c++20, string-literals

I noticed that msvc with C++20 allows a `std::string` array to be initialized by a string literal but both gcc and clang rejects it. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TzbKa35b4)

```
#include <string>
int main()
{ 
       std::string a[] = "a";   //msvc c++20 accepts while msvc c++17 rejects and gcc and clang all versions rejects this 
}
```

What should be the correct behavior here according to the C++ standard.

Comment: @jpa No this is a defect in the standard. See [CWG28244](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2824.html).

Comment: I'm curious, what is `std::size(a)` and `a[0].size()` after that initialization?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Strange thing that when I add `std::string b[] = {"a"}; std::cout << a << 1;` msvc with C++20 also starts giving other errors. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bPsr8jKrK)

Comment: @user12002570 Yeah, I got that too.  I'm now at home and can try it out. `std::size(a)`:  _"No matching overload"_. I then did `(sizeof(a) / sizeof *(a))` and got _"Error C2070 'std::string []': illegal sizeof operand"_. `a[0].size()` gives _"Error C4789 buffer 'a' of size 2 bytes will be overrun; 8 bytes will be written starting at offset 16"_ and _"Error C4789 buffer 'a' of size 2 bytes will be overrun; 16 bytes will be written starting at offset 0"_ - Utterly confusing.

Answer (score 3):

This is [CWG2824](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2824.html) that points out that the program should be **ill-formed** but the current wording(which was introduced through P0960R3) makes it well-formed.

Currently the wording in [dcl.init.general#16.5](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#16.5) says:

> Otherwise, if the destination type is an array, the object is initialized as follows. Let x1, . . . , xk be the elements of the expression-list. If the destination type is an array of unknown bound, it is defined as having k elements. Let n denote the array size after this potential adjustment. If k is greater than n, the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, the ith array element is copy-initialized with xi for each 1 ≤ i ≤ k, and value-initialized for each k < i ≤ n. For each 1 ≤ i < j ≤ n, every value computation and side effect associated with the initialization of the ith element of the array is sequenced before those associated with the initialization of the jth element.

---

While the correct/amended wording(as suggested in the CWG2824) is:

> Otherwise, if the destination type is an array, the object is initialized as follows. **The initializer shall be of the form ( expression-list ).** Let x1, . . . , xk be the elements of the expression-list. If the destination type is an array of unknown bound, it is defined as having k elements. Let n denote the array size after this potential adjustment. If k is greater than n, the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, the ith array element is copy-initialized with xi for each 1 ≤ i ≤ k, and value-initialized for each k < i ≤ n. For each 1 ≤ i < j ≤ n, every value computation and side effect associated with the initialization of the ith element of the array is sequenced before those associated with the initialization of the jth element.

Note the emphasized part in the above sentence which makes the code **ill-formed**.

---

Note that P0960 introduced the change in wording in dcl.init.general in C++20 only. That is, the defect report is for C++20 and onwards. For C++17 there is no need for any change in the wording because [dcl.init#17.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#17.5) already makes the program ill-formed.