# Copy-initialization of array type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Considering the example below, where `t` is declared as `int[1]`; is the initialization of `a` in `t a = t{};` legal according to the C++20 standard? Should the behavior of initialization `t a = t{};` in any way be  affected by marking `a` as `constexpr`? What does the C++20 standard say about this? And what about the initialization of `constexpr auto a = t{};`? Why does MSVC accept it?

```
static_assert([]{
    using t = int[1];
    constexpr t a{};        // all ok
    constexpr t a = {};     // all ok
    constexpr t a = t{};    // clang nope, gcc ok, msvc ok
    t a = t{};              // clang nope, gcc ok, msvc nope
    constexpr auto a = t{}; // clang nope, gcc nope, msvc ok
    return true;
}());
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/WrzMoEs3x)

---

The error message from Clang:

```
<source>:4:7: error: array initializer must be an initializer list
    4 |     t a = t{};
      |       ^
```

The error message from GCC:

```
<source>:4:24: error: taking address of temporary array
    4 |     constexpr auto a = t{};
      |                        ^~~
```

The error message MSVC:

```
<source>(4): error C2075: 'a': initialization requires a brace-enclosed
initializer list
```

Comment: This isn’t copy-list-initialization, but copy-initialization from a direct-list-initialized prvalue.

Comment: @DavisHerring Thanks for the correction. It's becoming increasingly difficult to get the naming right of everything without getting lured into the dark path of language-lawyering.

Comment: Related/dupe: [MSVC accepts std::string array initialized with string literal but gcc and clang rejects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77440123/msvc-accepts-stdstring-array-initialized-with-string-literal-but-gcc-and-clang)

Comment: @user12002570 I think that question is related but not exactly the same as this one.

Comment: @303 First the question doesn't have to be exctly the same to be a dupe. I closed this as a dupe because the answer given there is applicable here and can used as an answer here(which basically says that the code given in your question `t a = t{}` is ill-formed). That is, by reading the answer there, it should be clear to the readers that both of the programs(given in this question and the [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77440123/msvc-accepts-stdstring-array-initialized-with-string-literal-but-gcc-and-clang)) are ill-formed for the same reason and that the fundamental prblm is same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++17 `constexpr t a = t{};` and `t a = t{};` are both ill-formed, because initialization of `a` falls through until [[dcl.init]/17.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#17.5) (of draft N4659), which effectively demands that arrays, with an exception for initialization of character arrays by string literals, can only be initialized by an initializer of the form `{/*...*/}` or `= {/*...*/}` or `()`, where `/*...*/` is an optional comma-separated list of initializers. None of these match `t{}`.

In C++20 aggregate initialization from parentheses was added, so that initializing arrays with an initializer of the form `(/*...*/)` became allowed. So the fall-through case 17.5 in the initialization rules was replaced with rules for parenthesized aggregate initialization (see [[dcl.init.general]/16.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init#general-16.5) in draft N4868). Unfortunately the new wording assumes that if the bullet is reached, the array initializer must have the form `(/*...*/)`, ignoring the case in your question where `t{}` doesn't match any form.

So the C++20 standard lacks a specification for these cases.

[CWG issue 2824](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2824.html) has already been reported, although it is concerned with the special case where the initializer is a string literal, not a cast expression, and the array not a character array. Regardless, the resolution which is marked as "tentatively ready" and approved by CWG would make all of the remaining initializer forms ill-formed again, as in C++17.

So, once this is a proper defect report and implemented by the compiler vendors, both `constexpr t a = t{};` and `t a = t{};` should be ill-formed.

---

`constexpr auto a = t{};` is ill-formed, because the initialization is not a constant expression. You are trying to store a pointer into the temporary array materialized from `t{}`. This is not a permitted result of a constant expression per [[expr.const]/11.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#11.2).

Without `constexpr` it should be fine, but the pointer is immediately dangling after the initialization, because the temporary array is destroyed again. However, the initialization itself should be permitted, because [[conv.array]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.array) specifies that the array-to-pointer conversion also applies to array rvalues.

Comment: Also note that `auto a = t{};` would fail to compile on GCC 10-13, due to error `taking address of temporary array` but now finally seems to be fixed on GCC trunk.